# Increasing the font size makes the font smaller instead

Tags: fontsize, documentclass-writing

I screen capped my workspace in overleaf below:

[image]

The font size was initially at 12 pts as is in the command `\documentclass[titlepage,12 pt]{article}`. When I tried increasing the font size to 14 by changing to 14 pts in that same command, the text got smaller instead. Below is a screen capture:

[image]

Why did this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Besides the font size issue you mention, there are even more serious issues in your code that should definitely be addressed. Did you notice the red rectangle with the white number in it, right next to the recompile button in your first screenshot? Once you see this, the document in fact did not compile properly. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 4):

The `article` class only offers `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`, so `14pt` will be reset to `10pt`.

Consider using the `extarticle` class, which provides more font size support, from `8pt` to `20pt`.

Comment: Hi there! I tried your suggestion and it worked when I changed the font size to 14. However, when I tried any font size larger than that it gets reset to 10 pt. So maybe extarticle only supports up to 14pt?

Comment: @jboy I forgot to mention, you can only use `14pt`, `17pt` and `20pt`.

Comment: KOMA classes like ``scrartcl`` also offer a lot of freedom for font sizes.